# Нахождение всех множителей большого числа в заданном диапазоне

Tags: c++, алгоритм, простые-числа

Есть непростое число где-то между 796200000 и 796400000, какой есть наиболее быстрый способ найти все его делители? (в идеале с реализацией) (нужны именно делители, для последующего их использования)

Нет, в гугле меня не забанили, но я не смог быстро разобраться в невероятном разнообразии алгоритмов.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а зачем вам самый быстрый? Это разовая операция или предполагается много раз искать?

Comment: @pavel один раз, вроде бы. Это часть задачи, и хитрым способом удалось достать информацию о тесте, который программа не проходит из-за времени работы. Хотя, вполне возможно, в следующих тестах такие большие числа тоже будут

Comment: Самый быстрый в таком случае - использование msieve, поскольку не придется тратить времени на разработку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, как мне кажется - найти разложение на простые множители, а затем находить все возможные сочетания простых сомножителей в непростые.

Чтобы найти все простые, достаточно проверить делимость на простые, не большие 28284 (квадратный корень из максимального числа). Чтобы найти все простые - можно заранее то же решето Эратосфена использовать, с проверкой до 168 (очередной квадратный корень).

Что-то типа

```
vector<int> primus(int max)
{
    vector<int> p { 2 };
    vector<bool> prime(max+1, true);
    prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
    for(int i = 3; i<= max; i += 2)
        if (prime[i])
        {
            p.push_back(i);
            if (i*i <= max)
                for(int j= i*i; j <= max; j+=i)
                    prime[j] = false;
        }
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> p = primus(28300);

    int N = 796400000;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < p.size() && N > p[i]; ++i)
    {
        while (N%p[i] == 0)
        {
            cout << p[i] << endl;
            N /= p[i];
        }
    }
    if (N > 1) cout << N << endl;
}
```

Окончательная [полная программа](http://vpaste.net/703Eb) получения всех (не только простых!) делителей всех указанных чисел у меня на машине делает это за 2-3 секунды.

Comment: По-моему, сложновато...

Comment: @Qwertiy Что именно? Естественно, я не сидел и не вылизывал код, его можно сделать эффективнее...но проще - пожалуй, только полный перебор :)

Comment: А есть причины считать, что перебор не подходит? Там же меньше миллиарда числа, значит перебор до корня - меньше 65К операций. И я вообще не уверен, что куча операций с векторами - это сильно быстрее простого цикла.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, понятно, что если нужно ускорить - да, лучше написать через массивы, а не через вектора. Что до полного перебора - то разница в 11 раз примерно...

Comment: @Qwertiy А вообще, вся арифметика, которую можно описать встроенными типами - это просто мелочи, которые можно решать почти как угодно :) Вот когда пойдет речь о числах в 1000 знаков, тогда...

Comment: `if (i*i <= max)` - это можно убрать.

Comment: Действительно, такой вариант быстрее. http://ideone.com/wZHWEM vs http://ideone.com/akXlLV

Answer (score 3):

Заранeе прогнать 200 000 чисел и составить табличку. 200 килобайт есть у всех.

P.S. Да, я знаю, что при желании можно это ужать в 8 раз, пакуя в биты

P.P.S. Да, я знаю, что если хранить все с выравниванием, получится не 200 кило, а метр. Не страшно.

Comment: @gbd И что вы получите в этом бите? В лучшем случае - простое число или нет, но проблема-то найти ВСЕ делители. А тут уже веселее, потому что ВСЕХ делителей у ВСЕХ чисел - 4329853. Ну, если отбросить единицы и сами числа - то минус 400000, около 4 миллионов остается. Оно, конечно, и 16 мегабайт ерунда :), но ведь для одного числа просчет реально - 10 микросекунд (см. мой ответ). Стоит ли овчинка выделки?

Comment: @Harry стоит, на том основании, что время доступа даже к RAM у современных машин - 300 наносекунд в самом поганом случае (поход за байтами в другой NUMA-регион), итого выигрываем два порядка.

А так как 16 метров влезают в L3-кэш, время доступа к которому - десятки наносекунд, выигрываем три порядка. Так чья овчинка круче?

Comment: Конечно, ваша, кто бы сомневался :) Особенно для разового поиска :)

Comment: @Harry смотрите на этот код http://ideone.com/qbgOf1. А вот тема где такие коды люди делали, в комментах описание https://habrahabr.ru/post/164567/.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы найти все делители, надо искать только делители до корня из числа, а остальные получаются делением числа не его делитель. Осторожно обработать числа, являющиеся полными квадратами. В общем-то всё.

http://ideone.com/akXlLV - 5К чисел за 3 секунды

```
vector <int> getDivs(int n) {
  int q;
  vector <int> res;

  for (q=1; q*q<n; ++q) {
    if (n % q == 0) {
      res.push_back(q);
      res.push_back(n/q);
    }
  }

  if (q*q == n) {
    res.push_back(q);
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: действительно для маленьких (32-бита) чисел можно самый простой в лоб алгоритм использовать. Вот тоже самое на Питоне: `factors = lambda n: {f for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1) if n % i == 0 for f in [i, n//i]}`

Answer (score 1):

Разложение на множители.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/*
    Функция получения делителей числа N
    N - начальное число
    &divisor - ссылка на вектор, куда запишут результат
*/
void getDivisor(int N, vector<int>& divisor){
    int i = 2;
    while(N!=1){
        if(N % i == 0){
            N /= i;
            divisor.push_back(i);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int N;
    vector<int> divisor;
    cin >> N;

    getDivisor(N, divisor);

    for(int i=0; i<divisor.size(); ++i){
        cout << divisor[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Смысл в том, что в первую очередь переберутся самые базовые делители. Количество итераций цикла поиска будет равно максимальному простому делителю. Т.е. для числа `796400000` будет 181 проход цикла (делители: `2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 11, 181`)