# Не полное разложение на множители

Tags: c++

Написал программу, которая бы разлагала любое целое число на множители.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool isLCM (int num, int denum);
int fill_array(int &num, int *arr);

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

    int num;
    int *arr_of_denums = new int [1]; // массив для заполнения
    cin >> num;

    // в переменную n будет возвращен размер получившегося массива с делителями
    int n = fill_array(num, arr_of_denums);

    // вывод разложенного числа num на экран;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ( i == n - 1) cout << arr_of_denums[i]; //проверка на последний делитель
                            // если он последний, то ненадо после него ставить '*'
    else
        cout << arr_of_denums[i] << " * ";
    }

delete []arr_of_denums;
return 0;

}
// функция принимает число num и делитель denum
// в теле идет проверка на делимость num на denum
bool isLCM(int num, int denum) {

    if ( num%denum == 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}

// функция принимает число num и указатель на массив для заполнения arr
// массив заполняется делителями числа num
// и возвращает размер заполненного вектора
int fill_array (int &num, int *arr) {

    int denums[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11}; //массив делителей для числа num
    int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
            if (isLCM(num, denums[i])) {
                arr[j] = denums[i];
                num = num/denums[i];
                j++;
            }
            else i++;
        }

    return j;
}
```

программа работает, все выводит корректно, но есть одно но: она разлагает не полностью. Я попробовал разложить 1824, она вывела 2^5 * 3, хотя полным разложением будет 2^5 * 3 * 19. Собственно, как заставить ее выводить это самое 19? И заодно оцените, пожалуйста, как написан код. Я только учусь, хочу писать не только правильно, но и понятно :)

Comment: Если интересует именно разложение - посмотрите, например, [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540315/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы действительно хотите рассматривать в цикле только делители, указанные в массиве `denums`, то после завершения цикла вам надо еще добавить в массив `arr` то, что осталось от числа `num` (при условии, что `num` в конце не равен 1). В примере с разложением 1824 это как раз и будет ваше 19.

Только массив `arr_of_denums` у вас выделен размером всего 1. Так что больше одного числа в `arr_of_denums` заносить никак нельзя. Почему вы выделяете такой маленький массив?

Если отказаться от "голого" массива и использовать взамен `std::vector`, то реализация вашего алгоритма может выглядеть так

```
void fill_array(int num, std::vector<int> &arr) 
{
  const int denums[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 }; //массив делителей для числа num

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof denums / sizeof *denums;) {
    if (isLCM(num, denums[i])) {
      arr.push_back(denums[i]);
      num /= denums[i];
    }
    else 
      i++;
  }

  if (num != 1)
    arr.push_back(num);
}
```

и вызов

```
...
std::vector<int> arr_of_denums; 
fill_array(num, arr_of_denums);

// вывод разложенного числа num на экран;
for (int i = 0; i < arr_of_denums.size(); i++) {
  ...
```

---

Или даже так

```
std::vector<int> fill_array(int num) 
{
  const int denums[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 }; //массив делителей для числа num
  std::vector<int> arr;

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof denums / sizeof *denums;) {
    if (isLCM(num, denums[i])) {
      arr.push_back(denums[i]);
      num /= denums[i];
    }
    else 
      i++;
  }

  if (num != 1)
    arr.push_back(num);

  return arr;
}
```

и вызов

```
...
std::vector<int> arr_of_denums = fill_array(num);

// вывод разложенного числа num на экран;
for (int i = 0; i < arr_of_denums.size(); i++) {
  ...
```

---

Отдельно можно заметить, что выполняемые вами манипуляции практически один-в-один соответствуют простейшему алгоритму факторизации числа

```
unsigned n = 1824;

unsigned d = 2;
while (d < n)
  if (n % d == 0) {
    cout << d << " ";
    n /= d;
  }
  else
    ++d;

if (n != 1)
  cout << n << " ";

cout << endl;
```

Только этому алгоритму совсем не нужен заготовленный заранее массив простых делителей - он их сам находит (пусть и неэффективно). Может и вам ваш массив `denums` совсем ни к чему? Или задание именно такое?

Comment: На сколько я понял, я создал динамический массив, который будет расширятся по мере необходимости, вот и от балды туда написал 1, если бы можно, вообще скобки пустыми оставил, но компилятор ругается. Я пробовал сделать ваш вариант, добавлял в конце функции строки "++j;" и "arr[j] = num;"(простите, не знаю как в комментарии делать пример кода), но программа выводила вместо нужного числа мусор

Comment: @niki4iko: Массивы в С++ никогда сами не расширяются "по мере необходимости". Вам нужно либо самому вручную его расширять, либо (лучше) просто воспользоваться `std::vector`. А добавлять вам надо `arr[j] = num; ++j;`. Именно в таком порядке, а не наоборот.

Comment: Я пробовал std::vector, но сколько в инете не рылся, не нашел как его грамотно передать и заполнить в функции. По этому решил юзать обычный массив. Не подскажете, как тогда сделать с вектором?

Comment: массив denums действительно ни к чему, спасибо вам) задания никакого нет, это моя выдумка из головы :)

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что программа имеет неопределенное поведение, так как имеет место попытка обратиться к памяти за пределы динамически выделенного массива. В данном предложении

```
int *arr_of_denums = new int [1]; // массив для заполнения
```

выделяется массив, состоящий только из одного элемента. Однако в функции `fill_array` в цикле

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
        if (isLCM(num, denums[i])) {
            arr[j] = denums[i];
            ^^^^^^
            num = num/denums[i];
            j++;
        }
```

имеет место попытка обращение к 5 элементам массива.

Вместо вручную выделения динамически массива значительно надежнее и проще использовать стандартный контейнер `std::vector`.

Что касается стиля программирования. Данная функция имеет непонятный интерфейс

```
int fill_array(int &num, int *arr);
```

Какой смысл передавать переменную `num` по ссылке?

При этом логичнее объявить параметры в обратном порядке

```
int fill_array( int *arr, int num);
```

Функция с непонятным названием `isLCM` может быть вообще написана в одну строчку

```
bool isLCM(int num, int denum) 
{
    return num % denum == 0;
}
```

Возникает вопрос: а нужно ли для одной арифметической встроенной операции определять целую функцию?

В программе используются "магические" числа, как, например, число 5 в этом цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
```

Ну, и сам алгоритм страдает ограничением числа возможных простых чисел. Поэтому простое число 19 вы никак получить не можете. Для этого вам надо заново определять локальный массив, который на самом деле совершенно излишний.