# Разложить число n на k множителей

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, факторизация

Всем привет есть такая задача ,надо разложить число n на k множителей или вывести Impossible если это не возможно.Не знаю как можно решить .Можете помочь или подсказать алгоритм для решения этой задачи ?

Comment: Нужен хотя бы один способ или перечислить все возможные?

Comment: Один способ нужно вывести

Comment: Книжки не пробовали читать? Навскидку - Д. Кнут.

Comment: На правах Капитана Очевидность: единица и само `n` в качестве множителей не допускаются :)

Answer (score 2):

Разлагаем число на простые сомножители - факторизация на этом сайте разбиралась неоднократно. Допустим, это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если сумма всех `l` не меньше `k` - то можно :) Как вывести такое разбиение - понятно? Код писать не нужно?

Можете посмотреть ответы на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540315/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5).

Comment: k раз разлогать надо верно ?

Comment: Разлагать число `n` на сомножители. Например, `n = 2^2*3^1*5^2 = 300` Так как `2+1+2=5`, это число можно разложить до 5 множителей. На 6 и более - нельзя. Например, на 4: `300=2*2*3*25`...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы набрать `k` множителей, можно начать с `2` и увеличивать по одному пока все простые множители не закончатся или пока `k` множителей не наберётся, добавляя оставшийся множитель в конце (предполагая, что множители не могут быть равны `n` или `1` иначе ответ для любого `k > 0` был бы: `n` и `k-1` единиц -- исключая тривиальный случай, когда `k == 1` и `n` является множителем себя):

```
#include <vector>

template<class U>
std::vector<U> k_factors(U n, U k)
{
  std::vector<U> factors;
  if (k == 1) {
    factors.push_back(n);
    return factors;
  }
  else if (k > 1) {
    for (U f = 2; f*f <= n; ++f) {
      while (n % f == 0) { // found prime factor
        factors.push_back(f);
        n /= f;
        if (--k == 1 && n > 1) {
          factors.push_back(n);
          return factors; // found solution
        }
      }
    }
  }
  throw std::invalid_argument("Impossible");
}
```

Пример:

```
#include <cstdlib>      // exit
#include <iostream>
#include <string>       // stoul

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: k-factors <n> <k>\n";
    std::exit(2);
  }

  try {
    auto n = std::stoul(argv[1]), k = std::stoul(argv[2]);
    for (auto f : k_factors(n, k)) std::cout << f << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
  } catch(const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    std::exit(1);
  }
}
```

Результат:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 *.cc -o k-factors && ./k-factors 18446744073709551615 5
3 5 17 257 281479271743489
```

В этом случае даже простое деление в лоб достаточно быстро работает. Хотя `./k-factors 18446744073709551557 2` может занять какое-то время ;) В этом случае полезно проверить является ли `n` или `n/<small prime>` составным (к примеру, используя   [Тест Миллера — Рабина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)).