# Как ускорить код разложения числа на множители?

Tags: c++, математика, оптимизация, факторизация

есть код. он принимает число и раскладывает на множители.
сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool is_prime(int m) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(m); i++)
        if (m % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int i = 1;
    cin >> n;
    if (is_prime(n)) {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
    else {
        while (n != 1) {
            i++;
            if (is_prime(i)) {
                while (n % i == 0) {
                    n /= i;
                    cout << i;
                    if (n != 1) cout << "*";
                    else break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

как это можно ускорить?

Comment: '*' это разделение между простыми множителями

Comment: Посмотрите, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540315/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5). Или вообще выполните поиск по слову [факторизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 4):

```
int n;
cin >> n;
while(n%2 == 0)
{
    cout << "2 ";
    n /= 2;
}
if (n > 2)
{
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        while(n %i == 0)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) cout << n;
}
cout << endl;
```

Вот сравнение скоростей: http://ideone.com/8TY65i

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Конечно. Но чтоб не писать `cout << 2 << " ";`, пишу просто строку.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan См. код ТС - строки 8-11 от конца - он выводит все кратные делители.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что  Егор подумает о невыведенном '*' между  простыми делительями

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну, это уже будет "дайте воды напиться, а то так есть хочется, что и переночевать негде..." :) Это уже, как в книгах пишут - "оставим читателю в качестве самостоятельного задания"...